# How to solve application error while opening heroku website log in page?

Tags: heroku

I tried to log into my Heroku account but it seems like all the time i only the application error and the blank page with nothing on the screen. While i read the articles about this it says the application might have crashed, where as i created the new account and and also not able to log in to my old account just showing me application error with bank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your application has some error, which won't be displayed on Heroku by default for most frameworks.

From the console, try running `heroku logs --tail --app <yourapp>` then visit the page again. That should tell you what error you're running into then you can use Google or SO to help figure out how to fix them.

It's common for the issue to be one with a database not having been migrated, so that's a good first place to check.